# Insert after parent of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

What sort of selector would be I need in order to insert after the parent (divouter) of the test3 class in the example below? Thanks.

```
<div class='divouter'>
    <div class='divinner'>
        <input class=test1></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='divouter'>
    <div class='divinner'>
        <input class=test2></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='divouter'>
    <div class='divinner'>
        <input class=test3></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='divouter'>
    <div class='divinner'>
        <input class=test4></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the `$.after()` method:

```
$(".test3").closest(".divouter").after("<div>Foo</div>");
```

Or the `$.insertAfter()` method:

```
$("<div>Foo</div>").insertAfter( $(".test3").closest(".divouter") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.divouter:parent
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the "after()" method:

```
$('input.test3').focus(function() {
   $(this).closest('div.divouter').after('<div>Hi!</div>');
});
```