# Javascript: Parent element styling

Tags: javascript, parent

I have same situation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262659/insert-after-parent-of-element), but I don't want to write after, but to stylize parent element.

`$(".test3").closest(".divouter").after("<div>Foo</div>");`

This code from above works, but when I replace after with setAttribute or other stuff I'm getting below error:

`TypeError: $(".test3").closest(".divouter").setAttribute is not a function`

This is message for
`$(".test3").closest(".divouter").setattribute("style", "background-color:#DEDEDE;");`

Could you help me?

Thanks and I'm sorry for my English, Przemek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning a jQuery object, not a DOM node.  Which means you want jQuery's `attr()` method instead.

**EDIT:** You added some details and made it clear you want the `css()` jQuery method.

```
$(".test3").closest(".divouter").css("background-color", "#DEDEDE");
```